# Change argument value of a function after function is called

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function that is called many times within a for-loop, something like this:

```
def drawPatch(win, x, y, colour):
    pass

cycling_colours = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']

for i in range(25):
    for j in cycling_colours:
        drawPatch(win, x, y, j)
```

The `colour` is taken from a list and changes the `colour` of `drawPatch` each iteration. What I want to do is to grab the value of `colour` each iteration and store it in a list. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I hope there's enough information here.

Comment: Since you didn't quite specify the actual question, I'm not too sure of what you are actually asking. Are you asking us to help you implement `drawPatch` that has only a `pass` statement in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j` holds the value of each color.  So, all you need to do is append `j` to a list:

```
cycling_colours = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']
colors = []  # List to hold the values of j

for i in range(25):
    for j in cycling_colours:
        drawPatch(win, x, y, j)
        colors.append(j)
```

In the end, the `colors` list will hold all of the colors that you passed to `drawPatch` (each value of `colour` inside the function).

Comment: 34 seconds and I can accept your answer mate (:
The answer was so bloody simple. I was messing around with inspect() and all sorts of crazy nonsense. I need to remind myself "If it feels crazy, it probably is crazy"

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object. Pretty much the definition of an object is a bunch of functions, paired with state variables.

Objects are preferred to global variables because they're self-contained and you can pass them around.

```python
class DrawTool:

    def __init__(self):
        self.colour_list = []   # Initialize an empty state

    def drawPatch(self, win, x, y, colour):
        self.colour_list.append(colour) # Modify the state

        #TODO: more code here
        pass


cycling_colours = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']
my_tool = DrawTool()

for i in range(25):
    for j in cycling_colours:
        my_tool.drawPatch(win, x, y, j)
```